# Single Loop With Dual Content Area

Tags: loop, content, the-content

Is there a way to implement a single loop with dual content area.

**E.g. A single loop having 2 of**

`<?php the_content(); ?>`

**Dinstinguished as shown bellow with video and write-up respectively**

```
<?php the_content('video'); ?>

<?php the_content('write-up'); ?>
```

Comment: The first argument in `the_content()` is `$more_link_text`, I am not sure I am following what are you trying to achieve with that?

Answer (score 2):

Lets first start with a bit of knowledge-base:
[`the_content`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) is this

```
/**
 * Display the post content.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $more_link_text Optional. Content for when there is more text.
 * @param bool $strip_teaser Optional. Strip teaser content before the more text. Default is false.
 */
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
    $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    echo $content;
}
```

For more information on how the **content** is generated check: [`get_the_content()`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/)

So the `video` and `write-up` will be [`$more_link_text`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Designating_the_.22More.22_Text) values generating at a `<a href="...">$more_link_text</a>`

### Now back to you

If in your `content` you have information that you want to be [**filtered**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) (divided / separated) in two areas do this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_only_video')
the_content();
remove_filter('the_content', 'filter_only_video');

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_only_write')
the_content();
remove_filter('the_content', 'filter_only_write');
```

And in `functions.php` add this:

```
function filter_only_video($content) {
    // your code that only keeps that video part on (removing the rest)
    return $content;
}

function filter_only_write($content) {
    // your code that only keeps write-up part on (removing the rest)
    return $content;
}
```

If you write these two functions correctly you can show what you want in two separate places.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the default Twenty Fourteen theme code in `index.php`

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
             * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
             * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
        // Previous/next post navigation.
        twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

    else :
        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

    endif;
?>
```

The above code uses [`get_template_part();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) Which I believe is what you're trying to do.